# angularjs Parameter problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to have an action on that value when I press the Cart button after selecting the value of the select box.

Code

```
.controller('productPageCtrl', ['$scope', '$localstorage', '$window', function($scope, $localstorage, $window) {


  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    $scope.idx = $localstorage.get('product_info_idx');
    $scope.code = $localstorage.get('product_info_code');
    $scope.img = $localstorage.get('product_info_img');
    $scope.name = $localstorage.get('product_info_name');
    $scope.price = $localstorage.get('product_info_price');
    $scope.desc = $localstorage.get('product_info_desc');
    $scope.comment = $localstorage.get('product_info_comment');
    $scope.opt_product = $localstorage.get('product_info_opt_product');
    $scope.opt_price = $localstorage.get('product_info_opt_price');



    $scope.string = $scope.opt_product;


    $scope.string1 = $scope.opt_price;


    if ($scope.string != undefined && $scope.string1 != undefined) {
      $scope.arrString = new Array();
      $scope.arrString = $scope.string.split(',');

      $scope.arrString1 = new Array();
      $scope.arrString1 = $scope.string1.split(',');

      $scope.items = [];
      for (i = 0; i < $scope.arrString.length; i++) {

        $scope.blank = '';
        if ($scope.arrString1[i] == '') {
          $scope.aaa = ($scope.blank);
        } else {
          $scope.aaa = '(+' + $scope.arrString1[i] + '원)';
          $scope.bbb = $scope.arrString1[i];
        }

        $scope.items.push({
          name: $scope.arrString[i],

          view_price: $scope.aaa,
          price: $scope.bbb
        });
      }


      $scope.result = true;
    } else {
      $scope.result = false;
      console.log("no execute!");
    }

    $scope.addCart = function() {
      console.log("Cart");
    }

    $scope.addBuy = function() {
      console.log("Buy");
    }

    $scope.showSelectValue = function(price, mySelect) {
      if (mySelect == "") {
        mySelect = 0;
      }

      console.log("avg: " + (parseInt(price) + parseInt(mySelect)) + "원");

    }

  });
}])
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what's problem you fetch ?

Comment: explain more about your code

Comment: I want to get an option value when I press the cart button

Comment: In your addCart function you should pass the Id of the selected product (or the index of your item at object)  so your can do your senario with that particular item

Comment: The values ​​displayed on the console when you click the Select Options button are the total amount

avg: 132000
avg: 160000
avg: 198000

I want to output the value when clicking the cart button instead of the select option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$localstorage` does not have a get method anyway. you can use directly as an object:

```
$scope.idx = $localstorage['product_info_idx'];
```

Obviously this may not be the real problem.

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: @Keun $localStorage is a service in ngStorage module which does not have a get method. It is different from window.localStorage, which has getItem method to retrieve a key value. Keys stored using $localStorage can be set and get as if $localStorage is an object